# Convexity of $\int f(\frac{dP}{dQ})dQ$ for some convex $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove the convexity of $\int f(\frac{dP}{dQ})dQ$ for some convex $f$ and here is what I've done so far:

Since $f$ is convex, $f(\frac{dP}{dQ})$ is also convex w.r.t. $dP$ because $dQ$ behaves like a constant in this case, and as a result the whole integral is also convex.

If $f$ is convex $f(\frac{dP}{dQ})$ is also convex in $dQ$ for some constant $dP$. The multiplication of a convex function with $dQ$ is also convex, therefore the whole integral is also convex in $dQ$

Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) proves the convexity by saying that the mapping from (p,q) $\to$ $(q,f(p,q))$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I cannot see this immediately.

> Is my proof correct? How can one simply conlude that the mapping given by Wikipedia is obvious?

Thank you very much.